# Optimizing SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT) on a table increasing daily

Tags: query-performance, optimization, aws, distinct, aws-athena

Let's say we have a table `Daily_users` which has the columns `student_id, school_id, grade, timestamp`. We collect usage data of students daily and so the table grows daily (note that there could be multiple rows corresponding to the same student - the purpose is to track usages, so the student could be logging on and off, or using different apps etc). Using this table, we maintain another table called `unique_students_to_date` and it has the columns `school_id, grade, count.` The `count` is the number of unique students we have recorded for a pair of `(school_id, grade)`, so far.

Then, once yesterday passes, we run the nightly query to create the table `unique_students_to_date`:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT(student_id)) AS count,
       grade,
       school_id
FROM Daily_users
WHERE timestamp < '"today's date"'
GROUP BY school_id, grade
```

to get the unique students up to yesterday inclusive. This is a simple enough query and it does the job. However, I can't help but thinking there is lots of redundancies here. The table `Daily_users` today is only different by one day's worth of data from its yesterday's version, so when we do `COUNT(DISTINCT(student_id))`, we are re-doing a lots of the calculations we did yesterday.

So my question is  - Can we optimize this to at least to minimize the redundant calculations ?

Comment: Which database system and version are you using?

Comment: @J.D. the whole thing is happening in Athena and the (Glue) table is based on S3 buckets, partitioned by date (timestamp) and school_id, so I had to paraphrase a bunch here. I don't see any indexing defined anywhere though.